# How to execute multiple shell commands in android (non rooted device)?

Tags: java, android, linux, shell, ffmpeg

I am trying to execute two commands in my android app as given below :

```
Process process1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts");
process1.waitFor();

Process process2 = r.exec("ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts");
process2.waitFor();
```

But only the first command gets executed. The device is **not rooted**. How can i execute multiple commands?

*PS* : Went through various questions related to this but they are mostly for rooted devices and work using `su`

Comment: Are you sure the first command finishes?

Comment: Yes, because first command generates the intermediate file.

Comment: Try to get the Error Stream from the 2nd process using `getErrorStream()` and see if it throwing any error.

Comment: Thanks, solved the issues : output path was not correct and got this info from errorStream. :)

Comment: @DivyaMotiwala : May be you can add details on how you find it and what the issue was, as an answer, you can accept your own answer.:)